# C# string pairs into Tuple List

Tags: c#

I'm looking for the most efficient way to take a string like the example below and pull that into a list of `Tuple<uint, uint>`.

`<0,15><1,16><2,17><3,18>`

Here's what I have so far to split the pairs apart:

```
string s = "<0,15><1,16><2,17><3,18>";
string[] delimiters = { "<", ">" };
List<Tuple<uint, uint>> taglist = new List<Tuple<uint, uint>>();
string[] res = s.Split(delimiters, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
System.Console.WriteLine(res.Length);

foreach (string pairs in res)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine(pairs);
}
```

What I need to do next is convert those to uints to add to the tuple list, something like this, but not quite there....

```
uint[] pair = pairs.Split(",");
taglist.Add(new Tuple<uint, uint>(pair[0], pair[1]));
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, what was it that you found unsatisfactory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please also edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's easy: split the string by '>', trim with '<', then split each element with ',', select into (uint.Parse, uint.Parse). Try that, if you have problems, we can clear this out

Comment: How about post some code? My first idea should be remove first and last characters, split your string at "><", and re-split every items of the first iteration at ",". Put the values you take in a List of uint,uint objects and you reach your goal :)

Comment: As others have stated, providing a snippet of code would help. You can create a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) which will allow us to help you debug/try things out. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I think one potential solution is the following:

```
string s = "<0,15><1,16><2,17><3,18>";
string[] delimiters = { "<", ">" };
List<Tuple<uint, uint>> taglist = new List<Tuple<uint, uint>>();
string[] res = s.Split(delimiters, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
System.Console.WriteLine(res.Length);

foreach (string pairs in res)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(pairs);
    string[] delim = { "," };
    string[] pair = pairs.Split(delim, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    taglist.Add(new Tuple<uint, uint>(UInt32.Parse(pair[0]), UInt32.Parse(pair[1])));
}

foreach (Tuple<uint,uint> elem in taglist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```